# How to achieve continuous animation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

In the page I have an arrow, which is hidden at the beginning. When I click a button, the arrow shows.

I want a feature that the arrow continuously becomes bigger and returns to the original size, and then becomes bigger again, showing an expression of paying attention to where it points.

Comment: to who downvote this question: you don't have to help and answer, but why you downvote?

Comment: Because you've shown us no effort.

Comment: an animated gif would accomplish this as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *[DEMO jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ujewuv/3/edit#javascript,html,live)*

Code used:

```
<img id="arrow" src="arrow.png">
```

```
var ar = $('#arrow');
function pulsate(){ 
  ar.animate({width:'+=5',height:'+=5'},300,function(){
    ar.animate({width:'-=5',height:'-=5'},300,pulsate);
  });
}
pulsate();
```

(Hope that's what you were looking for...)

---

***P.S.***
You can also encapsulate the function like:

```
var ar = $('#arrow');
(function tic(){ 
  ar.animate({width:'+=5',height:'+=5'},300,function(){
    ar.animate({width:'-=5',height:'-=5'},300,tic);
  });
})();
```